# Load lookup fields based on dropdown list value in Infopath

Tags: office365, infopath

I have 2 lists
TestInfopath and TestMultiList

TestMultilist is having 2 fields - Title and GroupName
Title of TestMultilist is lookup in TestInfoPath and is shown as Multicheckboxes on infopath form that I have created.

I have created a dropdown list which populate data from GroupName field of TestMultilist and on selecting dropdown value, I need to show the lookup(Title in TestMultilist) corresponding to selected group only in Infopath form of TestInfopath. How can I achieve this? I am new to Infopath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the steps in the following link to show the lookup corresponding to selected group:

[How to populate values in text box depending upon the values of Drop down list in Infopath 2010?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/89dc809f-be39-4588-ae2f-249a8f2c5f26/how-to-populate-values-in-text-box-depending-upon-the-values-of-drop-down-list-in-infopath-2010?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

And also some related links for you:

[INFOPATH – QUERY SPECIFIC SHAREPOINT LIST DATA](https://wonderlaura.com/2011/08/01/infopath-query-specific-sharepoint-list-data/comment-page-1/)

[Get InfoPath to display lookup column value, not ID](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/get-infopath-to-display-lookup-column-value-not-id/)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will check it.